# After upgrading a wsl2 instance to Ubuntu 20 LTS, packages like build-essential cannot be installed

Tags: apt, dependencies, windows-subsystem-for-linux, do-release-upgrade

The

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 build-essential : Depends: gcc (>= 4:9.2) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: g++ (>= 4:9.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

If dig deeper

```
❯ sudo apt-get install -f libgcc-9-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgcc-9-dev : Depends: libitm1 (>= 9.3.0-10ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libatomic1 (>= 9.3.0-10ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: liblsan0 (>= 9.3.0-10ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libtsan0 (>= 9.3.0-10ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libubsan1 (>= 9.3.0-10ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libquadmath0 (>= 9.3.0-10ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
❯ sudo apt-get install -f libasan5 libatomic1 libgcc-s1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libgcc-s1 is already the newest version (10.1.0-2ubuntu1~18.04).
libgcc-s1 set to manually installed.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libatomic1 : Depends: gcc-10-base (= 10-20200411-0ubuntu1) but 10.1.0-2ubuntu1~18.04 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How to solve this dependency chain problem? force it to use the latest packages or downgrade to the recommended versions?

Comment: It's much easier to downgrade to the recommended versions. Remember that Ubuntu is a *snapshot* distro - all the versions sync every 6 months. When you wander away from that, you get held broken packages (version conflicts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @user535733 mentioned, *downgrading* is much easier.
I manage to downgrade all the dependencies and install the correct verison of gcc.
The trick is to make use of `aptitude`, that offers richer features than `apt`.

```
sudo apt install aptitude
sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude install build-essential
```

It gives me:

```
      Install the following packages:
1)      tcc [0.9.27-8 (focal)]

      Keep the following packages at their current version:
2)      build-essential [Not Installed]
3)      g++ [Not Installed]
4)      g++-9 [Not Installed]
5)      gcc [Not Installed]
6)      gcc-9 [Not Installed]
7)      libatomic1 [Not Installed]
8)      libgcc-9-dev [Not Installed]
9)      libitm1 [Not Installed]
10)     liblsan0 [Not Installed]
11)     libquadmath0 [Not Installed]
12)     libstdc++-9-dev [Not Installed]
13)     libtsan0 [Not Installed]
14)     libubsan1 [Not Installed]
```

Which is **not** what we want, so type `n`

Then aptitude will propose another solution, that looks like this:

```
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Downgrade the following packages:
1)     gcc-10-base [10.1.0-2ubuntu1~18.04 (now) -> 10-20200416-0ubuntu1 (focal)]
2)     libcc1-0 [10.1.0-2ubuntu1~18.04 (now) -> 10-20200416-0ubuntu1 (focal)]
3)     libgcc-s1 [10.1.0-2ubuntu1~18.04 (now) -> 10-20200416-0ubuntu1 (focal)]
4)     libgcc1 [1:10.1.0-2ubuntu1~18.04 (now) -> 1:10-20200416-0ubuntu1 (focal)]
5)     libgomp1 [10.1.0-2ubuntu1~18.04 (now) -> 10-20200416-0ubuntu1 (focal)]
6)     libstdc++6 [10.1.0-2ubuntu1~18.04 (now) -> 10-20200416-0ubuntu1 (focal)]



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] Y
```

We can accept this plan and then confirm the installtion.

```
Setting up build-essential (12.8ubuntu1) ...
```

When you see above line, it's done! Congratulations!